# calculating $Re{\frac{1}{(D^2+1)^2}e^{ix}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am calulating the real part of $ \frac{1}{(D^2+1)^2}e^{ix}$ $$Re{\frac{1}{(D^2+1)^2}e^{ix}}\implies Re{\frac{1}{(D-i)^2(D+i)^2}e^{ix}}\implies Re{\frac{1}{(D-i)^2(2i)^2}e^{ix}} \implies Re{\frac{-1}{4}\frac{1}{(D-i)^2}e^{ix}} $$$$\implies Re{\frac{-1}{4}\frac{1}{(D-i)^2}e^{ix}} \implies Re{\frac{-1}{4}\frac{x^2}{2!}e^{ix}}$$

where $D$ denotes the differential operator $d/dx$. In my book ,the answer is given different .Can someone suggest where i am applying the wrong formula ?

Comment: Why $(D+i)^2=(2i)^2$ ?

Comment: $\frac{1}{f(D)}e^{ax}=\frac{1}{f(a)}e^{ax}$, provided $f(a) \neq 0$ ..

Comment: This is a strange computation because $e^{ix}\in \operatorname{ker}(D^2+1)$. How is this being regularized?

Comment: What is the correct formula then ? @NinadMunshi

Comment: .....That is for you to tell us when you are providing an ordinarily nonsensical computation because it always context dependent.

Comment: The most general solution of $(D^2+1)^2e^{ix}$ is, I think, $(A+Bx+Cx^2)e^{ix}+De^{-ix}$. How do you decide which such function's real part you want? That's the regularization issue @NinadMunshi is getting at. (By the way, when you take such a real part, bear in mind the coefficients are in general complex.)